# Is English 'issue' etymologically related to Russian 'ищу'?

Tags: etymology

I've noted that English word **issue** sounds like Russian word **ищу**, which means "I search for".

Issue is something for which a solution needs to be found. So having an issue is closely related with searching for the way to solve it.

Is it an accident only or have those words some common ancestor deeply in etymological history (maybe even dating to PIE)?

Comment: The etymology of _issue_ can [be analysed here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=issue). I expect that questions on the etymology of Russian words are considered to be off-topic here.

Comment: In this kind it is cross-etymology. Would it be rather question for Linguistic.SE?

Comment: this kind of question usually gets sniffed at in Linguistics SE. Leave it here.

Comment: The word жир (fat) may sound like *jeer*, but that doesn't make them etymologically linked.

Comment: No, these are not related. However, Russian искать and English "ask" are.

Comment: @AlexB. thank you, so the **искать** has the same ancestor as **ask**, so as I understand it can't be related to **issue** because "issue" and "ask" are not related, am I thinking correctly?

Comment: @lechlukasz, right. You may want to take a look at this http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/ (in Russian)

Comment: @Robusto: more to the point, *issue* sounds *nothing* like *ищу*. They are not even remotely similar. This is a rather jarring example of awfully contrived folk etymology.

Comment: would the closers care to name the single reference source they are citing when closing the Q as general reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English *issue* ultimately traces to Proto-Indo European (PIE) **ei-* 'to go' via Latin *ex-ire* 'to go out'. Some witness words in Slavic of this PIE root are:

> Common Slavic *jiti (to go), *jido. (I go) >
>   Belarussian itsi (to go), Bulgarian ida (I go), Sloven idem (I go), Chekh jdu (I go), Slovak i'st' (to go), Lower Sorbian du (I go), Polabian eit (to go), Russian idti (to go), idu (I go)

The Russian is (I am supposing) from PIE *ayǝs-, with these notes:

> Slavic: *jīskātī; *jīskā 'Wunsch'
>   Baltic: *eîšk-ā̂- (1) vb.
>   Germanic: *aisk-ō- vb., *aisk=
>   Latin: aeruscāre 'betteln, bitten'
>   Other Italic: Umbr eiscurent 'arcessierint'

So it is reasonable to wonder, since English and Russian are related and do have many pairs of words related at the PIE level. But I don't think this is one.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Almost every question of the form "The word X in language A is rather like the word Y in language B: are they related?" has the answer No, unless the languages are closely related or there is a reason why the word should have been borrowed. Surface similarity is rarely significant.

Comment: But some words have common roots dating back to Pre-Indo-European language. I like to check sometimes the etymology for the words that sound similar in Polish and English to discover that they have roots in Latin or Greek, but the dictionaries rarely are looking deeper in history...

Comment: @lechlukasz, I hope you understand that you are comparing Modern English (as it is spoken now) and Modern Russian.

Comment: I find it rather difficult to comprehend that surface similarity is rarely significant. I believe lots of types of linguistic exchanges (verbal cues) must have transpired between people of different regions in history and still do, and which sometimes may have resulted in some words being adopted into certain languages. How is that not significant?

Comment: Of course that is so, Mohit, but unless the words have been borrowed recently, sound-changes in the different languages will usually have obscured any similarity, and created new apparent similarities between unrelated words. There are exceptions, but they are rare if the languages are not closely related. For example. Grimm's law has changed most stop consonants in Germanic languages, so the English _have_ and German _haben_ share a root not with Latin _habere_ ('be accustomed') as one might guess, but with Latin _capere_ ('take, seize').